# Why does mplayer exit Bash while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor, mplayer

When I run the below script `mplayer` gives the below error and doesn't continue the while loop after pressing return. if I replace `mplayer` with `mpv` it works. I have to use mplayer, as `mpv` doesn't support the video formats I need to play.

I suspect the problem is related to file descriptor redirection, but I had to do that to get user input to work in a while loop with piped data from `find`.

**Purpose**

The goal of the script is I want to play each file in a directory, and after watching the video it should prompt me for what to do with the file. E.g. delete, rename, move.

**Question**

Can anyone see what the problem is, or perhaps how to work around it?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

exec 3<&0 # redirect std input to a different file descriptor
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" | while read f; do

mplayer -really-quiet -msglevel all=-1 "$f"

echo $f
printf "What to do: "
IFS= read -r -u3 opt

done
exec 3<&- # Close fd3
```

The error is

```
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Assertion 'm' failed at pulse/thread-mainloop.c:175, function pa_threaded_mainloop_lock(). Aborting.
```

Comment: I have no idea about mplayer internal but in my understanding you are just looping on the files you find in your directory right? 
I don't understand why your loop is so complex!
Would it be impossible to just do `for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*'); do ...; done;` and avoid the redirection of std? Let me know if it works!

Comment: Just run `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 mplayer -really-quiet -msglevel all=-1` and it should work fine for the space issue (no loop anymore, remove the `for` construction)

Comment: the syntax to loop over files in current directory is just  `for f in *; do [[ -f $f ]] || continue; ... ;done`, this will work with any character in filenames including spaces, only in command calls must use quotes `"$f"` as it's already done

Comment: By default, `read` will interpret backslashes before spaces and line feeds, and otherwise strip them — This is rarely expected or desired. Normally you just want to read data, which is what `read -r` does. You should always use `-r` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul That did the trick. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to answer from comment, shell syntax to loop over files in current directory is just :

```
for f in *; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    ... do something with "$f"
done
```

This will work with any character in filenames including spaces.

The `-f` test is to ensure $f is a file (otherwise continue).

This handles also the case where there is no file : glob is not expanded and `"$f"` is `"*"`.

The issue with mplayer may be due to the pipe writing to standard input of `while .. done` as to mplayer input is inherited from caller if mplayer is consuming whole input the caller will have an empty input. another fix could be to explicitly redirect input inside while loop `exec 0</dev/null` or just for mplayer's command `mplayer .. </dev/null`. or just `exec 0</dev/tty` and in this last case `exec 3<&0`/`read -r -u3 opt` is no more needed just `read -r opt`